# Recursion output ambiguity

Tags: java

Ok so i am just learning recursion and i am confused on one point. 
This is the code

```
public class RecursiveDemo {
  public static void showRecursion (int num) {
   System.out.println("Entering method. num = " + num);
    if (num > 1) {
      showRecursion(num - 1);
    }
    System.out.println("Leaving method. num = " + num);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    showRecursion(2);
  }
}
```

The output i am getting is :

```
Entering method. num = 2
Entering method. num = 1
Leaving method. num = 1
Leaving method. num = 2
```

My question is why am i getting the output "`Leaving method. num = 2`". Shouldn't it stop at "`Leaving method. num = 1`" since num has already reached 1?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger?

Comment: +1 for the homework tag.

Comment: Sorry for asking this but i have absolutely no idea how to use the debugger. How shall i use it?

Comment: Debugger? I just put print statements everywhere

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once the original invocation of this method leaves the if statement, it passes to  `System.out.println("Leaving method. num = " + num);`. Since you invoked the message originally with value `2`, `2` is the value of `num` for this part of the code.

Your code runs like this (pseudocode):

```
Start First Call
    if statement
       Start Second call
           Skips if statement
           Print from Second Call
       End of Second Call
    End of if Statement
    Print From First Call
End of First Call
```

It looks like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of recursion.
When you call your method with `(num-1)` as arguments, the parent call (the first call, in this case), retains the value `num` as its argument, which is `2`, in this case.

Comment: But if 2 is the value of num shouldn't it go back into the if statement?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if that clears that up for you or not.

Comment: Oh okie doke. Now i understand. The reason why it prints a 2 is because even though a second call is made the first call is still active right?

Comment: Yes! and it resumes when the second call ends.

Answer (score 6):

So let's comment out the line below

```
//showRecursion(num - 1);
```

What would you get? It must be

```
 Entering method. num = 2
 Leaving method. num = 2
```

And if you uncomment the line above. You should get the one you had.

Comment: Ok i understand what you are saying but when i commented out the line above i got the output :Leaving method. num = 1 Leaving method. num = 2. Now i understand why i got "leaving method num= 1" but i do not understand why i got "Leaving method. num = 2" since num was already reduced to 1

Comment: That's because after num is reduced, meaning after calling showRecursion(1), system still has things to do according to your code: 
    System.out.println("Leaving method. num = " + 2);

Answer (score 4):

No.

`main` will call `showRecursion(2)`, which in turn will call `showRecursion(1)` (so you get two "Entering" messages).  At which point, the condition will fail, so no more recursion occurs.  So now the program simply begins returning from each function call in turn, printing both of the "Leaving" messages.

Answer (score 3):

It's because the initial call to `showRecursion(2)` hasn't finished yet.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following:

```
public static void showFirstRecursion (int num) {
  System.out.println("Entering method. num = " + num);
  if (num > 1) {
    showSecondRecursion(num - 1);
  }
  System.out.println("Leaving method. num = " + num);
}

public static void showSecondRecursion (int num) {
  System.out.println("Entering method. num = " + num);
  if (num > 1) {
    showThirdRecursion(num - 1);
  }
  System.out.println("Leaving method. num = " + num);
}

// I won't bother showing an implementation for showThirdRecursion, because it won't be called.

public static void main(String[] args){
  showFirstRecursion(2);
}
```

No problem here, right? You'd expect to see the first method entered, second entered, (third not entered because num == 0), second left, first left.

There is *really nothing special* about recursion. It's just making a function call that **happens** to be calling the function that the call is a part of. A recursive call behaves, conceptually, in all respects like any other function call. The trick is the *design* of a recursive *algorithm*, i.e., coming up with a reason *why* you'd want to call the same function you're already in.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. It cleared up most of my questions about recursion.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already cover the specific question, but [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html) is some information on using a debugger. This tutorial is for Eclipse, but pretty much tells you what you need to know for any visual debugger.

The basics are pretty straightforward, and it would be well worth your time to at least learn how to step through the code. A debugger is an invaluable tool for quickly verifying the logic of your program, and is far easier than scattering print statements everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try "showRecursion(5);".

[Answer: This is recursion. There's more than one copy of the variable "num" in memory.  "num" is a parameter; it's not a field, and it's not static.]

Answer (score 0):

So what I understood was
with every method call, Stack is getting populated ie. 2,1
but when i>1 doesn't matches it returns/breaks the call and control is given to the system.out.println line, that prints the value starting from the top of stack ie 1,2

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation